# Bialgebraic structure of Sklyanin algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, integrable-systems

Does Sklyanin algebra (which is an elliptic extension of the quantum group) admit a bialgebra structure or even Hopf algebraic structure? Or is it proved that it is impossible to have such a structure?

Note that the algebra is defined as four generators $S_0, S_{\alpha = 1,2,3}$ and
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& \{ S_0, S_{\alpha} \} = 2 J_{\beta \gamma} S_{\beta} S_{\gamma}\\[0.5em]
& \{ S_{\alpha}, S_{\beta} \} = -2 S_0 S_{\gamma}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$ is the cyclic permutation of $1,2,3$.

Moreover, if one so far cannot find such bialgebraic structure, is it still possible to define tensor product representation of the algebra?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/259058/85967 is also related to this question. It actually poses the first question for an arbitrary algebra.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In response to your first question, there is no Hopf structure on any Sklyanin algebra of any dimension. See Corollary 2.8 (i) of the following paper:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.06687v1.pdf

Comment: So, the Sklyanin algebras are non-admissible, in the sense of the definition posed at: https://mathoverflow.net/q/259058/85967